# What is the problem ASP.Net Core Error CS1061

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
> 'AddDefaultIdentity' and no accessible extension method
> 'AddDefaultIdentity' accepting a first argument of type
> 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly
> reference?)   WebHesab    C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\WebHesab\WebHesab\Startup.cs 36  Active

[image]

Comment: copy and past the code here... then ensure you have nuget package Identity for entityframe work...

Comment: Does your IServiceCollection match the calling ServiceCollection class?  Make sure all public functions for your ServiceCollection class are mentioned in the IServiceCollection

Comment: Put `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` at the top of your `startup.cs` If you right-click on the red underline, it will tell you how to fix it and even do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add a reference to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` nuget package in order to use `AddDefaultIdentity`.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI --version 5.0.2
```